# Extjs 5 Ext.app.ViewModel, stores - load data using proxy

Tags: ajax, extjs-mvc, extjs5

I'm trying load data from server and bind data. Such method does not work. Whats wrong?

```
Ext.define('Configurator.view.activityType.ActivityTypeModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.activityTypeModel',
    stores: {
      ticketStatusSummary: {
       fields: ['id', 'title', 'name'],
       autoLoad: true,
       proxy: {
                url: '{prefix}/{entityName:uncapitalize}',
                pageParam: '{pagaParam}',
                startParam: '{startParam}',
                limitParam: '{limitParam}'
            }  }
    }
...
```

Comment: Where do you bind all the data in your viewmodel? You should only use a bind syntax for values you're going to actually provide.

Comment: Hi Evan. I bind the data to the view, was the Problem with the fact that the proxy did not make a request to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is resolve.
Problem is with the proxy - unknown **reader**

```
reader: {
            type: 'json',           
         }
```

Actual code:

```
Ext.define('Configurator.view.activityType.ActivityTypeModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.activityTypeModel',
    stores: {
      ticketStatusSummary: {
       fields: ['id', 'title', 'name'],
       autoLoad: true,
       proxy: {
                url: '{prefix}/{entityName:uncapitalize}',
                pageParam: '{pagaParam}',
                startParam: '{startParam}',
                limitParam: '{limitParam}',
                reader: {
                        type: 'json',           
                }
            }  
        }
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Im surprised that you have to define all of this inside your viewcontroller...

You should be able to do: (I'm still trying to actually figure this out, I dont think it is the right code.)

```
stores:{
    ticketSummary:'MyApp.stores.TicketSummary'
}
```